# Center td inside a fixed width div

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed width div, and i need to center the two td in the middle.
here's my fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyrOZm

html:

```
    <div class="managed-form">
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label title="Company">
            Company
          </label>
          <input size="30" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
          <label title="Title">
            Title
          </label>
          <input class="" name="Title" size="30" type="text" value="">
        </td>
      </tr>
<table>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.managed-form{
  background-color: #5B8F22;
  width: 311px;
  height: 369px;
}
```

Comment: You have [invalid html](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_td.asp)

Comment: @alirezasafian fixed it

Answer (score 3):

Make you `inputs` width 100%. Like this:

```
input[type="text"]{
  width:100%;
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmePEx)

Comment: doing this in my project didnt work as planned http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=f21f858 what could be the reason?

Comment: I would probably remove the `size="30"` from the input tags since you are setting your size in css. If that doesn't fix it then inspect the element and see if any css styles are overriding your `width:100%` declaration. You could also try and write it this way: `windth:100% !important;` but that is kinda hacky and not recommended

Comment: did your recommendation still no luck

Comment: It looks like your table cell might have a set width. Can you try adding this: `.managed-form td{ width: 50%; }` and see if you get any better results?

Comment: no luck - thanks for your help, anything else to try

Comment: can you right click the textbox in the browser and select "Inspect Element" and provide a screen shot of what that looks like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92404/discussion-between-alundra-the-dreamwalker-and-zgood).

Answer (score 1):

I added border-box to all elements (which may not be something you want to apply universally on the whole page, it will affect padding spacing etc.)

But, it does seem to center the items better:

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/chuddayo/pen/rOGZqQ)

CSS:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.managed-form{background-color: #5B8F22;
    width: 311px;
    height: 369px;}

input[type="text"]{
  width:100%;
}
```

Further Reading:
[Box-Sizing](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-sizing/)

Answer (score -1):

I would do it like this

HTML:

```
<div class="managed-form">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="company">
                Company:<br>
                <input type="text">
            </label>
        </td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="title">
                Title:<br>
                <input tyoe="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.managed-form
{
    background-color:red;
    width: 311px;
    height: 369px;
}
table {
 margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```